# Pseudo-domain onion not work ([Warn] Refusing to connect to the IPv6 address...)

Tags: configuration, ipv6

I have a problem. When I want to connect to the pseudo-domain onion tor return me information:

> [Warn] Refusing to connect to the IPv6 address [scrubbed] because Port
>   has NoIPv6Traffic set.

To the Torrc file I added lines:

```
DNSPort 9053
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
AutomapHostsSuffixes .exit,.onion
```

What should I do?

Normal domains work good.

--- update to comment

I checked it. In the file I can have only this three lines. Something I should add?

Answer (score 1):

If IPv6 working in your setup? i.e. it can be disabled in `sysctl` or in kernel - so no AutomapHosts-like features will work with IPv6, if it's disabled in OS. Also here some check-list:

- `GeoIPv6File` must be specified,
- In `OrPort` no flag `IPv4Only` must be specified,
- `ClientPreferIPv6ORPort` *should* be set to `auto`,
- `ClientUseIPv6` should **not** be set to `0`
- `VirtualAddrNetworkIPv6` - if using AutomapHosts - can be also used and it's a big bonus
- `PreferIPv6Automap` - set it to `on` if you're preferring IPv6
- `PreferIPv6` and `IPv6Traffic` are enabling you to use IPv6 for exits - use these flags in `SocksPort` line, by default SOCKS in Tor **does not** handle IPv6! <<---- **this can be your particular case due to the error message you've posted**

Try to add the strings needed to your `torrc` explicitly. If you will still have problems - drop me a line, we'll se further.